# How to retrieve name of the class in java through Utility methods?

Tags: java, logging

I am trying to reduce the line of codes in my application. For logging purpose, I have a method which I created earlier in every class to retrieve the name of class and method.

```
    public String currentClassAndMethod() {
    // getStackTrace()[1] method return implementing method name at 1st index
    return "Inside class: " + getClass().getSimpleName() + " in method name: "
            + new Throwable().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();

}
```

The above method works fine when it is inside the implementing class(Controller, Service classes etc) but when I put it inside a Util class it gives me the name of the Util class.

```
    @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
    logger.info(ecommUtils.currentClassAndMethod());
    List<Product> productList = productService.getProducts();
    return productList;

}
```

I can't make this method static. What I want to achieve is to define this method in a single place and then call this method from every class.

Comment: I think you may be able to configure the logger itself to print out the name of the class and method, depending on your logging framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some serious issues here:

1. Calling `getStackTrace()` is really quite slow.
2. You're doing the job in the wrong place; as a rule, you want the logging system itself to take care of this. Your code should just be worried about what string needs to be logged, and at what level. Your logging framework's job is how to render this information (for example, it's up to the logging framework to add the location of the log statement and the current time, for example.
3. getClass() is always returning the class that your `currentClassAndMethod()` method is in, and therefore not what you want. This would work:

```
int nestingLevel = 1;
StackTraceElement elem = new Throwable().getStackTrace[nestingLevel];
return elem.getFileName() + "::" + elem.getMethodName() + "::" + elem.getLineNumber();
// there is elem.getClassName() too if you prefer that.
```

So, that's how you'd do it.. if you want to do it. I advise you don't. If you must, note that you can speed things up quite a lot if you move the invocation of this 'get me the location' code inside the logging infrastructure, for example in a log handler (I don't know what logging framework you use, so I have to be vague about it) – that way, if you log at a level that you're ignoring, you don't need to spend the expensive time fetching a stack trace just for the generated string to make its way through the logging infrastructure and get completely ignored because it's below the configured 'log at this level'.